# Rails omniauth not refreshing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, omniauth

I'm using the omniauth-twitter gem to authenticate users and to fill in names, avatars, etc. with this in my User.rb file

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice("provider", "uid")).first || create_from_omniauth(auth)
  end

  def self.create_from_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
      user.nickname = auth["info"]["nickname"]
      user.location = auth["info"]["location"]
      user.image = auth["info"]["image"].sub("_normal", "")
      user.description = auth["info"]["description"]
    end
  end
end
```

Works great, except I happened to change my avatar in Twitter and noticed that the data never changes even after I log out and reauthorize. It would be nice if data like location, image, description got refreshed each time a user logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the workings of that logic are up to you. Here's an example of a possible solution:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  user = find_by(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)) || initialize_from_omniauth(auth) # Rails 4
  user = where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first || initialize_from_omniauth(auth) # Rails 3
  user.update_dynamic_attributes(auth)
end

def self.initialize_from_omniauth(auth)
  new do |user|
    user.provider = auth[:provider]
    user.uid = auth[:uid]
    user.name = auth[:info][:name]
  end
end

def update_dynamic_attributes(auth)
  self.location = auth[:info][:location]
  self.image = auth[:info][:image]
  self.description = auth[:info][:description]
  save!
  self
end
```

Also, you don't have to do this:

```
auth["info"]["image"].sub("_normal", "")
```

As the `omniauth-twitter` gem can already do that for you if you use the [`image_size` option](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter#authentication-options):

```
OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, ENV["TWITTER_KEY"], ENV["TWITTER_SECRET"], {
    :image_size => 'original'
  }
end
```

Comment: Finally got around to trying this and data is still not updating. It's very strange because the approach looks solid.

Comment: I forgot that you have to use `self` inside of the instance method, otherwise it just creates a local variable.

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work. Even when I clear the image, description, and/or location fields in the console (and clear all caches, restart server, etc.) it never gets changed when I re-authorize with Twitter. I delete the user entirely and get the latest profile... but that's really desirable. :) Very weird.

Comment: I tried the code this time and it definitely works. Check out [this sample application](https://github.com/guilhermesimoes/omniauth-popup).

Comment: I more closely followed the pattern the Sessions controller in the sample you provided, and it worked. Looks like I was skipping everything if I found an existing user in my Sessions controller. Thanks a million for the example!

Comment: Sorry it took so long to help you out. But yey, it finally worked! :clap: